# Duda con BUCLE FOR (ahora en PIC C COMPILER)

Tags: c, loops

Que tal nuevamente amigos, ya resovieron mi duda, pero funciono en un compilador de C, ahora estoy programando en pic C compiler, pero me marca que el segundo bucle se vuelve infinito (siempre es verdadero, lo ejecuta normal, pero al final empieza a prender los leds de manera muy aleatoria), solo cambiando la variable j a SIGNED si me funciona (estoy haciendo el clásico ejemplo del "auto fantástico") no entiendo por que, alguien sabrá a que se debe??

```
#include<16f886.h>
#fuses xt,nowdt
#use delay(clock=4M)
#use standard_io(b)

int vec[8]={1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128};
int j=0,i=0;

void main(){
    {
    for(i=0;i<=7;i++)
    {
        output_b(vec[i]);
        delay_ms(200);
    }

    for(j=7;j>=0;j--)
    {
        output_b(vec[j]);
        delay_ms(200);

    }     
}
```

> ///El error:
>   Warning 203 "Vector.c" Line 19(1,1); Condition always TRUE
>   //Uso de la memoria
>   ///0 errores, 1 advertencia

Como me respondieron en mi pregunta pasada si funciona (j>=0), pero siempre y cuando j sea SIGNED, cabe mencionar que este concepto de colocar el signed lo encontré en un ejemplo parecido al mio, y no se por que funciona, alguien me lo podrá explicar? . Gracias de antemano

Comment: No se ha modificado el código, sólo lo he puesto un poco más ordenado... ¿Si quiera compila lo que pones aquí?

Comment: si compila, y lo simula en proteus, pero marca la advrtencia, y al momento de entrar al segundo for empieza a prender los leds de forma desordenada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque **no lo indicas**, el aviso se produce aquí:

```
for( j = 7; j >= 0; j-- )
```

y es consecuencia de

```
int j = 0;
```

Tal y como indicas, si usas `signed`, la *advertencia* (que no error) desaparece.

La explicación es muy sencilla: tu compilador usa `unsigned int` por defecto, y los datos de ese tipo **nunca pueden ser negativos**; es imposible.

Sin entrar en detalles técnicos, para tipos de datos **sin signo** (supuestos de 32 bits):

```
int x = 0;

--x;

printf( "%u\n", x );
```

> 4294967296

Creo que con esta imagen ([tomada de aquí](https://compsecurityconcepts.wordpress.com/2014/12/31/integer-overflow/)) se entiende mejor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes pensar en ellos como si fueran cícliclos: cuando llegan al último valor posible, vuelven a empezar por el principio. Y al revés: cuando llegas al primero, vuelves a empezar por el último.

Teniendo eso en mente, ya sabes el porqué **no son posibles valores negativos en tipos `unsigned`**

Es por eso por lo que el compilador te avisa: puesto que no hay valores negativos, `j >= 0` **se cumplirá siempre**.

Por eso mismo no te dice nada si usas `signed`. Por definición, esos tipos **sin tienen signo**, por lo que pueden existir valores negativos ... que si son menores que `0`.

Comment: - puesto que no hay valores negativos, j >= 0 se cumplirá siempre-     Muy bien, gracias amigo, entonces si entendí, j "buscara" que halla números negativos para que se cumpla estrictamente la condición j>=0 verdad? Si entiendo, lo hace para "verificar" que j>=0 se cumpla??

Comment: @GabrielMT La regla es muy simple: si el tipo de dato es `unsigned`, **solo puedes usar** `>`, `<`, `==` y `!=`. Cualquier otro operador **se cumplirá siempre**, el compilador lo sabe, y te *avisa* de ello. Sin embargo, con tipos `signed`, puedes usar **cualquier** operador sin problemas :-)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo, excelente explicación, saludos :)